# Why is 3 modulo 11 equal to 3?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Why is 3 modulo 11 equal to 3? The expression in coding syntax is usually

```
 3 % 11
```

This is the remainder of dividing 3 by 11, correct? Then the result should be 11 since that would be the remainder. What am I understanding wrong?

Comment: No. If you take `3` divided by `11`, you get a quotient of `0` and a remainder of `3`. So `3 % 11` is `3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

```
3 / 11 == 0
3 % 11 == 3
0 * 11 + 3 == 3
```

Answer (score 2):

3 / 11 = 0 with 3 remaining. The answer to any n mod m can never be equal to or greater than m, by definition.

Answer (score 1):

```
      0
    -------
11  | 3
    | 0
    |
    -------
      3 = Answer
```